# Proper way of navigating user from login/signup page to home page after authentication in flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, flutter-navigation

I just wanna know the professional way of navigating from login/signup page to home page after successful authentication using firebase. Can any one provide me the best way of doing it. I have tried many ways but most of them caused some kind of problem . I tried streeambuilder but it did not navigate to home page after authentication.

Comment: "I have tried many ways" It's much more likely that someone here can help if you show us the try that you thought really should've worked. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: can you show me a way how you do it .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a viewmodel or class where you called the firebase webservice and check in `if else` if authentication is successful then call this

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => HomePage()));
```

and pass the context as a callback.